# Running a function periodically in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

Im writing an app in Django to monitor certain services in a group of servers. I would like to have the views updated periodically. So far I've looked at writing custom admin commands ([link here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/)) and have {% ifchanged %} tags in my template. I just wanted to know if this is the best approach or if there is a better way to do it, like auto refresh certain portions of the webpage or something else. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting to run something periodically, I would suggest looking at [celery](http://celeryproject.org/) tasks (see [here](http://bitkickers.blogspot.com/2010/07/djangocelery-quickstart-or-how-i.html) for a brief tutorial).

From there, like Craig Trader mentioned, you could use AJAX to check the status of the tasks ([django-celery](http://celeryproject.org/docs/django-celery/) has some built in [views](http://celeryproject.org/docs/django-celery/reference/djcelery.views.html) and [urls](http://celeryproject.org/docs/django-celery/reference/djcelery.urls.html) you can use).

Comment: Thanks. I looked at celery but I found chronograph a bit easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

The [`ifchanged` template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#ifchanged) is really for when you're processing a series of objects within a template, and want to do something if a field changes from one object to the next.  That probably won't meet your needs.

If you just want the data backing your models to be updated periodically, then writing a custom command and running it periodically with a cron job makes the most sense.

If you want the user interface to refresh itself periodically, there are lots of ways to do that: meta-refresh tags, javascript/jquery tricks, or even using AJAX to update the displayed data.